# Optimizing writing/updating new values of an array

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I'm working on a code where I calculate the distance between all the particles wrt each other and calculate forces between them.
The code is as follows:

```
void calcCoulombicRepForces(double xc[], double yc[], double zc[], double fx[], double fy[], double fz[], int Np, double q1q2){
    double x1,y1,z1,xhat,yhat,zhat,dist,distcube;
    for (int i  = 0; i < Np; i++){
        double sumX = 0.0; double sumY = 0.0; double sumZ = 0.0; 
        x1 = xc[i];
        y1 = yc[i];
        z1 = zc[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < Np; j++){
            xhat = xc[j]-x1;
            yhat = yc[j]-y1;
            zhat = zc[j]-z1;
            dist = sqrt(xhat*xhat + yhat*yhat + zhat*zhat);
            distcube = dist*dist*dist;
            sumX += xhat/distcube;
            sumY += yhat/distcube;
            sumZ += zhat/distcube;
        }
        fx[i] = -q1q2*sumX;
        fy[i] = -q1q2*sumY;
        fz[i] = -q1q2*sumZ;
    }
}
```

xc, yc and zc are the coordinates. fx, fy and fz are the forces.
The size of each array here is Np ~ 58000 elements.

The code is working fine but 99% of the time taken by this function is spent to write/update values inside the array i.e., these three line

```
    fx[i] = -q1q2*sumX;
    fy[i] = -q1q2*sumY;
    fz[i] = -q1q2*sumZ;
```

I read somewhere it might be because its trying to access the arrays fx, fy and fz from higher level cache or the RAM.
If so, is there a way to optimise these three lines so that array writing/updating becomes faster in anyway? If not, am I doing something wrong here?
Please let me know if I'm missing something that I should have included.

Comment: How did you measure or profile to figure out those three simple assignments are taking that much time? Did you remember to build with compiler optimizations enabled? And have you thought about using a single array of point structures instead? That should help quite a lot when it comes to caching.

Comment: I timed the function using chrono, then I commented these three lines and timed it again. I'm using -O3 -ffast-math during compiling. Can you provide a hint how the structure should be. Thanks

Comment: Where are you even using xc, yc, zc, etc.?

Comment: There is some error while posting the code. xc,yc,zc is xcn,ycn,zcn. Sorry about that. I have updated it.

Comment: @DJMech If you remove the three assignments, the compiler will optimize away your whole function body, because it doesn't have any side effects anymore.

Comment: @DJMech, if you comment that 3 lines, a compiler can optimize out all the function except chrono output, since it has no observable effects. Espessially with -03.

Comment: it's not about your problem, but when `i` and `j` are equal, your `distcube` is equal to 0, so you are dividing by 0

Comment: Do not focus too much on micro-optimizing this. There are far larger gains to be had by not considering particles that are too far away to matter. You can do this by aggregating particles into a grid structure and ignoring grid cells that are too far away.

Comment: @Raffallo Till now, I have avoided this problem either by using "if (i != j)" or by calculating the upper triangular (from i+1 to Np) and the lower triangular matrix (from 0 to i) separately inside the i loop/block.

Comment: @DJMech oh, I found one problem with your code. You are calculating distances between points (and other values) too many times. For example, these values, for the last two points are calculated in each loop, so are calculated `(Np - 1)` times instead of just once

Comment: another pain point: your use of separate arrays means your CPU cache cannot be utilized as efficiently. Switching to a `struct{double x,y,z} positions[], forces[]` should give another micro-improvement

Comment: On an unrelated note, the Coulomb force is inverse square, not inverse cube as in your program.

Comment: @SimonGoater Indeed it is but in vector expression we multiply each component with a unit vector in that direction. Dimension wise it's still inversely proportional to distance square.

Comment: @Botje I'll look into structures.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't read it properly. xhat etc. look like components of a unit vector, but they're not. Perhaps a variable name change would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of benchmarking is just producing non-sense.

If you remove the three assignments, then the function has no side effects left at all and it also doesn't return anything, so the compiler is going to optimize away the whole function body.

That's why apparently all the time taken the by function is spent in the three assignments.

Comment: Thanks I understood this part. So there is no way to optimize this step? Like - I thought of making a local array inside the function and then copy the whole array but that again is the same thing. Any kind of suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: @DJMech It doesn't matter at all. It is obvious that most time will be spent in the inner loop if `Np` isn't small (and if it is small, there is no need to optimize anyway). You'll get more out of trying to improve the distance calculation. In any case the algorithm has Theta(Np^2) time complexity either way. So in the end it will be slow for `Np` no matter what. If you want to get significant improvements consider instead what approximations you can make to get an algorithm that has lower time complexity as suggested in the question comments, e.g. by excluding far away particles.